# Como fazer o SpeechRecognition ouvir os sons do sistema (youtube, zoom e etc..) ao invés do microfone?

Tags: python

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
import speech_recognition as sr


CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
RATE = 44100



p = pyaudio.PyAudio()


#stream usando o as_loopback para pegar som do SO
   
stream = p.open(
    format = FORMAT,
    channels = 2,
    rate = RATE,
    input=True,
    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
    input_device_index=16,)

#Função para ouvir e reconhecer a fala
def ouvir_microfone():
    #Habilita o microfone do usuário
    microfone = sr.Recognizer()
    
    
    
    #usando o microfone
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        
        #Chama um algoritmo de reducao de ruidos no som
        microfone.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        
        
        #Frase para o usuario dizer algo
        print("Diga alguma coisa: ")
        
        #Armazena o que foi dito numa variavel
        audio = microfone.listen(source)
        
    try:
        
        #Passa a variável para o algoritmo reconhecedor de padroes
        frase = microfone.recognize_google(audio,language='pt-BR')

        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()
        p.terminate()

        if "aula" in frase:
            pyautogui.PAUSE = 1
            pyautogui.keyDown('win')  # hold down the shift key
            pyautogui.press('1')     # press the left arrow key
            pyautogui.press('1')     # press the left arrow key
            pyautogui.keyUp('win')
            pyautogui.click(x=1311, y=988)
            pyautogui.write("Presente professor")
            pyautogui.press('enter')
            pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'tab') 
            

            

        
        #Retorna a frase pronunciada
        print("Você disse: " + frase)
        
    #Se nao reconheceu o padrao de fala, exibe a mensagem
    except sr.UnkownValueError:
        print("Não entendi")
        
    return frase
    

ouvir_microfone()
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá! Tente mudar o valor da variável `input_device_index`. 
Quando você cria a variável `stream`, você ta passando diversos parâmetros para o PyAudio, essa variável é a responsável por selecionar de qual aparelho o pacote vai capturar o audio:

```
stream = p.open(
    format = FORMAT,
    channels = 11,
    rate = RATE,
    input=True,
    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
    input_device_index=#ALTERAR AQUI,
    as_loopback=True)
```

PS: Talvez você tenha que procurar por esses 'devices' com:

```
for i in range(0, p.get_device_count()):
    print(i, p.get_device_info_by_index(i)['name'])
```

Dessa forma você consegue ver qual lista de aparelhos que o PyAudio consegue capturar, e escolher qual você quer. Me avisa se conseguir.

Se ainda tiver dúvidas, dá uma olhada [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/430001/como-gravar-sons-do-alto-falante-e-do-microfone-simultaneamente-com-o-python-no?rq=1), nesse caso ele usa duas variáveis `stream`, e faz captura simultânea de dois aparelhos (canais).

Comment: Não consegui amigo, não sei como fazer o speech_recognition reconhecer, vou mostrar como ficou

Comment: Mas então seu problema mudou? Você ta conseguindo gravar o som que sai do Windows agora? Porque seu problema era em gravar o Audio do PC, ao invés do audio do Mic. Você conseguiu fazer isso?

Comment: Não sei se consigo te ajudar com o pacote do Speech Recognition porque nunca usei esse pacote. Se ele não consegue ler, mas você está gravando corretamente, imagino que o problema seja no formato do arquivo que está sendo criado pelo PyAudio

Comment: Se acha que o problema ainda é na hora de gravar o audio dos seus alto falantes, ia recomenda que você habilitasse a opção "Mixagem Estéro", como é ensinado [nesse site](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/39532/how-to-enable-stereo-mix-in-windows-7-to-record-audio/) e que eu peguei [dessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57928940/16019213)